# How to get skew values from displayObject transform?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, linear-algebra, displayobject, skew

There is no straight methods to get skew values in **DisplayObject**. Please, help me to get **skewX** and **skewY** values from transformation matrix of **DisplayObject** - I am forgot all the linear algebra stuff...

Will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var matrix:Matrix = target.transform.matrix;
    var yAngle:Number = matrix.b / Math.PI * 180;
    var xAngle:Number = matrix.c / Math.PI * 180;
```

xAngle and yAngle - skew in degrees

next time read reference to [Matrix](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html) class